# Ray Power Equation for Bent Fiber Optics

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, power, fiber-optics

I came across this equation while reading the book, Optical Waveguide Theory (by Snyder and Love) on page 182:

[image]

where P(0) is the initial power from the straight fiber, R is the curvature radius, ρ is the core radius, $θ_c(r)$ is the complement of the local critical angle, γ is the power attenuation coefficient, ɸ is the angular displacement along the bent fiber and $θ_z$ is the incident angle with respect to the optical axis.

Here comes my question: **Can someone explain why or how the integral limit with respect to the angles are from -$θ_c(r)$ to $θ_c(r)$? What is the meaning of negative $θ_c(r)$?** Any help is appreciated!